# How to update an existing excel file with pear library?

Tags: excel, pear

I have an excel file with some data. Can i update the second column (cell number may: b2, b3, b4, b5 ....) of that excel using pear library?

I have used the Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader() to read excel:

```
$xlsFormatFile = UPLOADS_DIR.DS."my_xls_format.xls";

require_once (EXCEL_LIB_DIR.DS.'[excel_reader2.php][1]');

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($xlsFormatFile);

echo $data->dump(true, true);//Shows the content of the excel file in browser
```

Now how can I update the data and save.
Please give me any sample code or any advice welcome....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader package does what it says, it **reads** xls spreadsheet file, it cannot write those files. There are writers as well: Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer can be used to create a spreadsheet file, but cannot read (although I've had people who've told me otherwise). You could use both packages together, but you'd need to write the "glue" code to take the result of the reader and use that to create a new file (with the same name) using the writer.

The alternative is using a library such as [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) that can both read and write.